# CUDA: Modifying CMake causes linking error

Tags: gcc, cmake, cuda, linker-errors, nvcc

I had a CMake project. In order to use some cuda kernels in the project, i tried to first changed the name of *mian.**c** to main.**cu***.

When i cmake the project, the **Makefile** is generated fine but when i try to build the project using **make**, the building process prompt me following:

`main.cu: undefined reference to <ftns>`

The building process works perfectly fine when i modify the *main.**cu** to main.**c***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved.
The extension of the main was .cu and the  which it was directly calling were in .c extensions. So i also changed the extension of those files to .cu and it worked.